Migrating to java 11 but getting javax imports when I want jakarta when I use the wsimport feature from jaxws-maven-plugin plugin
I'm migrating an existing java web application from java 8 to java 11.
In the pom.xml file the project does invoke javaxws-maven-plugin:
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>queueRequest</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <vmArgs>
                            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                        </vmArgs>
                        <packageName>my.company.client</packageName>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>${project.basedir}/src/conf/xml-resources/test/client.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

When I compile the project the generated java files from the wsimport contains javax imports and I get compilation errors /Hello.java:[4,33] package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist

I'm trying to have it so that it has import jakarta.* imports and not import javax.*
Can someone help point me in the right direction on how to resolve it?
The pom file plugin references a client.wsdl file, and that file references a client_xsd.xsd in a xsd:schema section.
If it helps here's the contents of both files.
client.wsdl:
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
             xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
             xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://my.company.com/"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             targetNamespace="http://my.company.com/" name="clientRequest">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://my.company.com/"
                        schemaLocation="client_xsd.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="hello">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
    </message>
    <message name="helloResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="clientRequest">
        <operation name="hello">
            <input wsam:Action="http://my.company.com/clientRequest/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://my.company.com/clientRequest/helloResponse"
                    message="tns:helloResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="clientRequestPortBinding" type="tns:clientRequest">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="hello">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="clientRequest">
        <port name="queueRequestPort" binding="tns:clientRequestPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://my.company.com/clientRequest/clientRequest"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>

client_xsd.xsd:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://my.company.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://my.company.com/">

    <xs:element name="hello" type="tns:hello"/>
    <xs:element name="helloResponse" type="tns:helloResponse"/>

    <xs:complexType name="hello">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="helloResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>


RomanC, you originally voted to close with "needs more details". This is not true. The question is crystal clear. When the question is simply beyond your understanding please move on or just fix the tags.
